# jQuery event upon selection of a suggested item on a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to run a function upon each modification of a textbox control as soon as the user is typing. the event `.keyup()` is fine for most of the cases.

However, browsers (like Chrome or Firefox) may suggest autocompletion entries for textbox controls (probably because the @name or @id of the input control is known).

**Unfortunately, I can't have any of the below events fired when "clicking on a suggested entry".** ( `.keyup()` fires when selected with keyboard )

```
$('input#email')
  .click(function() { console.log('click'); })
  .keyup(function() { console.log('keyup'); })
  .keydown(function() { console.log('keydown'); })
  .change(function() { console.log('change'); })
  .focus(function() { console.log('focus'); })
  .blur(function() { console.log('blur'); });
```

As much as possible, I'd like to avoid using a `setInterval()` periodical check.

**Is there a way to detect this "select a suggestion" event ?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bind `propertychange` event:

```
$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() { 

    var input = this.value.trim();
    [...]   

});
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks for this (even if I'm a bit far from this project now). I note that it fires when clicking on a suggested entry (as requested) but not when selecting it by keyboard. Registering the event handler also with _keyup_ may be useful to fill-in this gap.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no, there is no event for detecting a suggestion selection. You could try looking at DOM mutation observers but I'm uncertain if these cover attribute changes, and there is little support for this API so far anyway.

So if you really need to handle this case then I think `setInterval` is your only option.

Edit: 3 years later you can use `propertychange` with jQuery as in the new accepted answer (which I assume uses mutation observers under the hood).

Comment: My investigations seem to converge to this conclusion.. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Besides `setInterval`, I think a more clear approach is detecting when a field/textareas has focus, copying its current value and comparing it to its value after it loses focus. A drawback is that you only know that it's changed once the field loses focus. However, a simple way to overcome this is to implement a `change` listener as well, besides the one I just described.

Answer (score 3):

alternative solution disable autocomplete and handle other events like keyup,keydown etc

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The change event seems to works fine, but does require you to click away